# Using phpExcel out of controller

Tags: symfony, controller, phpexcel

I would use the PHPExcel bundle other than in a controller (to create a service), but I can not get it to work under these conditions.

Here is what I have written in the function 'execute' of the command file:

class XportXcelPourAnalyseCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
....
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){
....
        $phpExcelObject = $this->getContainer('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject();

```
    $phpExcelObject->getProperties()->setCreator("liuggio")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("Giulio De Donato")
        ->setTitle("Office 2005 XLSX Test Document")
        ->setSubject("Office 2005 XLSX Test Document")
        ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2005 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
        ->setKeywords("office 2005 openxml php")
        ->setCategory("Test result file");
    $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!');
    $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // create the writer
    $writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel5');
    // create the response
    $response = $this->get('phpexcel')->createStreamedResponse($writer);
    // adding headers
    $dispositionHeader = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        'stream-file.xls'
    );
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'maxage=1');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $dispositionHeader);

    return $response;
    $output->writeln('done');
}
```

Comment: you need to use it in a service ? add some more details what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @ M Khalid Junaid  I want to use it as service in the execute method of a symfony command

Answer (score 0):

when you create a command by following [*docs*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html) your command class inherits `ContainerAwareCommand` class and you can get the container by calling `$this->getContainer()` inside the `execute()` function of your command class, once you have container you can access any service like to get the excel service you can get it like `$this->getContainer()->get('phpexcel')`

```
class GenerateExcelCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        //..............
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $excelObj= $this->getContainer()->get('phpexcel');
        // do your excel stuff here 
        $phpExcelObject = $excelObj->createPHPExcelObject('file.xls');
        $writer = $excelObj->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel5');
        $writer->save('file.xls');
        $output->writeln('done');
    }
}
```

> By using ContainerAwareCommand as the base class for the command (instead of the more basic Command), you have access to the service container. In other words, you have access to any configured service

[`Getting Services from the Service Container`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container)

Comment: @
M Khalid Junaid I have modified my question and added the code of my 'execute' function. This function does'nt work

Comment: @YvonPLANCADE you are running command so returning a file object as response will do nothing its not like a browser where file will start downloading you have to save file somewhere in directory then you can see the excel stuff thats why in my demo code i provided you the example of `save` not a downloadable output

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid Ok, but I have also the error:
'code'PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method appDevDebugProjectContainer::createPHPExcelObject() in G:\wamp\www\Gescomptes_versions\gescomptes_BE\src\Gc\RequetesBundle\Comm
and\XportXcelPourAnalyseCommand.php on line 70
'code'

Comment: @YvonPLANCADE you are not following my answer correctly `$this->getContainer('phpexcel')` this is wrong and this one is correct `$this->getContainer()->get('phpexcel')` please read again my answer i am storing excel object in `$excelObj` and all functions of excel will be called by `$excelObj` only sorry i can't correct your whole code i can just guide you only